Is it possible to get a callback when the selection changes in the graph editor?
Is it possible to get a callback in Python when the selection changes in the graph editor?
I need to synchronize a custom property with the coordinate of the selected point in the graph editor, and every time the selection changes I need to synchronize the custom property again.
